# Running on ubuntu terminal giving unexpected line breaks

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-terminal, konsole

When i try to run my cpp code with multiple testcases on ubuntu then i get unexpected results. It works fine when i run testcases one by one but when i copy and paste testcases then terminal gives unexpected line breaks

For example

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n<<"Hello"<<endl;
    }
}
```

when i run this code with testcase
5
4
3
2
1
5

by directly copying and pasting i get following result

```
5
4
3
2
1
5 4Hello
3Hello
2Hello
1Hello

5Hello
```

instead of

```
5
4
3
2
1
5 
4Hello
3Hello
2Hello
1Hello
5Hello
```

can anyone tell whats the problem i have tried for many hours researching but i am not getting any solution.
I have tried konsole,xterm,gnome terminal all are giving same results on directly doing copy paste of testcases.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste

```
5
4
3
2
1
5
```

instead of

```
5
4
3
2
1
5
```

The issue is happening because when you are using the second case the following happens -

1. First 5 is read and with the `'\n'` character, the `cin` knows that the read is complete. Thus 5 is assigned to `t`.
2. In the loop all the integers are read till 1, and 5 is not read, because it's not being followed by the `'\n'` character. Thus you have the 4 outputs on the terminal -

```
 4Hello
3Hello
2Hello
1Hello
```

and after pressing the `enter key`, the `'\n'` character is fed to the input and then 5 is read and `5Hello` is printed.

If we use the first case, then the output comes as desired, because every integer is followed by the `'\n'` charcater.

Comment: This didn't worked. Actually the same problem came. 
What i did is manually give t and then pasted rest things but then also there were extra line breaks for last output.